# python script to find out how many columns and which ones are different than the 1st one

Tags: python

I have this test data below: where the c1,c2 etc.. represent columns.

My goal is to run a python script to identify how many columns and which ones have different numbers than the 1st column (which is C1). in this example C1 is 888 but it can be other values. I need to find out how many and which columns in the same row will contain different values than C1. Right now this is stored in a csv and I don't have so much code written for this because I am struggling to figure out how to approach this:

```
C1   C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9 C10 C11 C12 C13 C14 C15 C16 C17  C18     C19
888 888 888 888 888 888 888 888 888 888 888 888 888 888 888 999 999 239.66  214.75
```

code

```
with open(r'path','r') as r:
    reader=csv.DictReader(r)
    diff=[]
    x=0
    for row in reader:
        diff.append(row)
```

Comment: When you say column you mean row? C1 is a column, so there's no first column of C1

Comment: When you say "how many and which columns have different values", what output are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @JuanC I interpreted that as "the first column: C1"

Comment: sorry check my edits

Comment: As I understand it @ziggy wants to check for row in the dataframe, which columns share the same value than C1 ?

Comment: Could you post an example of input and desired output with at least two rows, to be sure of what you're asking ?

Comment: @JuanC yes that is what I want. I just need to return for that row how many columns have different values and if they are different values which columns are they. I don't have a desired output on what it needs to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply search for keys which don't match the column of interest and check whether their value matches the value of 'c1'.

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as r:
    reader = csv.DictReader(r)
    diff = []
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        rowdiff = []
        val = row['c1']
        for key in row:
            if key != 'c1' and row[key] != val:
                rowdiff += [key]
        # Place tuple of (# differences, column keys) in diff
        diff.append((len(rowdiff), rowdiff))

    print(diff)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pandas` here.

Let's say your dataframe is `df`.

```
    C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6   C7   C8   C9  C10  C11  C12  C13  C14  C15  C16  C17     C18     C19
0  888  888  888  888  888  888  888  888  888  888  888  888  888  888  888  999  999  239.66  214.75

mask = df.eq(df.iloc[0, 0]) # boolean mask

df[~mask].dropna(axis=1)

   C16  C17     C18     C19
0  999  999  239.66  214.75
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code fills a dictionary on which every key is a row and every value is which columns don't match with first column.

```
dict_cols={}
for row in range(len(reader)):
    same_cols=[]
    for col in reader.columns[1:]:

        if reader[reader.columns[0]][row]!=reader[col][row]:
            same_cols.append(col)
    dict_cols[row]=same_cols
```

Maybe it's a bit convoluted, though